# Default Category in Lingpipe's Text Categorization

Tags: nlp, categorization

I'm using the Lingpipe's Text Categorization feature in an application. The classifier is working just fine, however, I've noticed the it does not support a "Default Category". That is, there is no possibility the text will be categorized as "neutral", if it does not fit a specified category. Is there a way I can do this? Perhaps if I determine a threshold for the score.

I appreciate any sugestions. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean text *classification*?